# Tinymce inline editor did not appear over the selected text

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I'm trying to initialize a TinyMCE editor with the editor floating over the selected text but it appears in a static place i used this for the 
inline editor

Example Code:-
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Qhgaab

Comment: Without seeing running code I don't believe people will be able to help you. Can you create a example of this issue at http://fiddle.tinymce.com/?

Comment: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Qhgaab

Comment: When I click in the `myeditablediv` div the editor appears over the div and allows me to edit the content ... what were you expecting to have happen?

Comment: i want the editor to appear exactly over the selected text suppose i have about 100 so i can't do this without scrolling top to can reach the editor

Comment: That's not how the editor works ... it takes over the div that you reference in the init.

Comment: inline attribute shouldn't mean that it should be over the selected line i guess, that's why i asked this question?

Comment: That is not how it works.  The inline editor takes over the block element that you assign to the editor.  There is no mode/configuration where TinyMCE will just appear over the selected text.

Comment: that is what i want to do ,if there is no other way to do it using tinymce can you mention other editor that can do that task